# How do i remove numbered lines from the main text in doccument using Matlab-prettifier

Tags: matlab-prettifier

I'm using

```
\usepackage[numbered]{matlab-prettifier}
```

but want to insert one line in the main document WITHOUT line numbers.
I'm adding MATLAB codes in appendix for which I need the numbers.

I'm inserting my codes in main document as:

```
\begin{lstlisting}[style=Matlab-editor]
.......
\end{lstlisting}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Add `numbers=none` to the `lstlisting` options:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[numbered]{matlab-prettifier}
\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}[style=Matlab-editor, numbers=none]
.......
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```